# Install google-auth in raspberry (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, google-authentication

I'm installing `google-auth` on raspberry pi 3 using `pip`:

```
pip install google-auth

pip install --upgrade google-auth
```

But when I used `import google.auth`, I get the following error `No module named 'google.auth'`

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linu
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information
>>> import google.auth
 Traceback (most recent call last)
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module
ImportError: No module named 'google.auth
```

Comment: Please add your output as code-formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank for your suggest

Comment: Try to remove it by `pip uninstall google-auth` and then install it again. If doesn't work' remove the possible .egg file and install again

Comment: How can I do remove the possible .egg. When I remove google-auth and reinstall, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `pip` by `sudo`,then try installing it using:

```
sudo pip install google-auth
```

Comment: I'm using python3 as the default. So the `pip` is equivalent to `pip3`